# grid.getView().refreshNode() : View is not defined

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am working on existing code and I receive the error:

> Uncaught Reference error: View is not defined

on this line:

```
grid.getView().refreshNode(store.indexOfId(record.data.UserId));
```

Can anyone tell me where might be the error and how I can solve it?
What I want is to update only the record of the grid and not the whole grid

*more information:*

```
var grid= #{UsersGridPannel2};
var store = grid.getStore();
var recToUpdate = store.getById(record.data.UserId);

recToUpdate.set(record.getData());
recToUpdate.commit();                                    

grid.getView().refreshNode(store.indexOfId(record.data.UserId));
```

the grid definition:

```
<ext:GridPanel runat="server" ID="UsersGridPannel2" AutoScroll="true" Width="1610" Height="550" EmptyText="No Users" >
                <Bin> 
                    <ext:Store runat="server" ID="storeUsersRoles" OnReadData="storeUsersRoles_ReadData">
                        <Model>
                            <ext:Model runat="server" IDProperty="RoleId" ID="UsersRoleModel1">
                                <Fields>
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="ApplicationId" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="RoleId" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="RoleName" />
                                </Fields>
                            </ext:Model>
                        </Model>
                    </ext:Store>
                    <ext:Store runat="server" ID="storeUsersSites" OnReadData="storeUsersSites_ReadData">
                        <Model>
                            <ext:Model runat="server" IDProperty="Siteid" ID="UsersSitesModel1">
                                <Fields>
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="Siteid" Type="Int" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="CTid" Type="Int" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="InstitutionId" Type="Int" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="clientid" Type="Int" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="Type" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="FullName" />
                                    <ext:ModelField Name="FullSiteName" />
                                </Fields>
                            </ext:Model>
                        </Model>
                    </ext:Store>
                </Bin>
.....
```

Comment: We are going to need a bit more info to be of any help here - where is this line from? where is the variable `grid` defined? and what else has happened to it between being defined and this line?

Comment: @Theo is the new info enough?